# How to get the id clicked after jquery/ajax load Showing or returning multiple button

Tags: jquery, ajax

index.php
    //script

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='div_com'>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $("#div_com").load('showingcomment.php')
        },1000);

 $(".reply_reply231").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
    $("#txta").val('');
  });

</script>
```

showingcomment.php

```
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
```

show this from index

```
echo " <div id='divtextarea'><textarea id='txta'></textarea>
<input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row2['CommentID']."'>

<button id='reply_reply'name='reply' type='button'>Reply</button></div></br>                                                               
";             
                                    }
```

//after i show it i cant alert() what button has been clicked

Comment: where is the code where you are trying to get the id of the clicked button

Comment: "SELECT Username, Content_Reply, Date_Posted,CommentID FROM reply_comment where ArticleID=$id"

Comment: I did not ask for the query! You said "it cant show what button has been clicked". Did you write code to do that ? If yes, you should include that in your original question as that is relevant to your problem. Also spend a minute to format the code in your question.

Comment: after i displayed it in index.php..i want to alert which button i clicked i search stack but still no help..:(

Comment: Sorry ! Still not understanding what you want! Please update the question with relevant details.Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry =D my bad haha...the <button id='reply_reply'name='reply' type='button'>Reply</button> will be displayed to index.php ..i simply use jquery  $("#div_com").load('showingcomment.php')
        },1000); to show the stuff from showcomment.php thats it..

Comment: @Shyju there i edit it thats it .....sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand what the issue is due to lack of question info...If you're just wanting the id of the button clicked, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("button").click(function() {

         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         alert(id);

      });

});
```

I've made a jsBin to help out: http://jsbin.com/vuhoquworo/edit?html,output

Comment: no luck :( i just use .load(showcomment.php); in index.php..the showcomment contains an external html to show it to #div_com...then i want the button i clicked to alert();